# hazelcast data distribution

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have hazelcast server distributed on multiple nodes.  I am assuming that hazelcast would distribute any IMap data across the cluster so every node would have data belonging to the map.  Is that something which should happen by default once the cluster is established or does it require a code or config setting in hazelcast.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data distribution should take place as long as you have multiple nodes in a cluster (I believe the requirement would be that they all need to have the config - programmatic or config file).  Replication (different from distribution) can be controlled by the config.  If you wish to look more into how data can be assigned to partitions, you can check the hazelcast docs for reference - a suggested route would be to add the partition name to the map to achieve better data access (for read heavy apps).